# Best way of storing objects to have fast access?

Tags: python

OK, I try one more time, sorry if I was unclear it was my first attempt to ask here something.

```
# I have such class
# p1 is immutable and uniq. It's using for search
# p2 is mutable parameter
class SomeHashableObject():
    def __init__(self, p1)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = []

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.p1)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.p1==other.p1
```

For example I have 2 different of SomeHashableObject.

```
#Creating and saving
obj_1 = SomeHashableObject(1)
obj_1.p2 = ['a', 'b']
obj_2 = SomeHashableObject(4)
obj_2.p2 = ['c', 'd']
```

Now I'm want to store my objects and then find one where p1=4

## First Way to store and find (list)

```
# Storing
obj_list = [obj_1, obj_2]
# Searching
result = next(obj for obj in obj_list if obj.p1==4)
```

## Second Way to store and find (hashtable)

```
# Storing
obj_dict = {
    obj_1: obj_1,
    obj_2: obj_2
}
# Searching
obj_to_search = SomeHashableObject(4)
result = obj_dict[obj_to_search]
```

Is it the second way acceptable(or better)?
I hope now everything is clear)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. `dictionary[obj_to_find].obj_attribute` You already have `obj_to_find`, why would you need the dict lookup `dictionary[obj_to_find]` which will return exactly the same `obj_to_find`?

Comment: Normally the key and value in a dictionary are different. Otherwise, if you already have the object, why look it up in the dictionary? Perhaps your class is weird in such a way that instances that are apparently equal are different in detail, but that has led to confusing code in this case.

Comment: It would probably be more useful to have `{'some_key': obj_to_find}`, otherwise you need the object to find the object, which doesn't make sense

Comment: If you have the key Hash tables (dictionaries in Python) are always faster than finding a value in a list (O(1) vs O(n))

Comment: @Mntfr Faster in some circumstances. Not quite _always_ faster.

Comment: @khelwood I'm curious, when is a time when lookup from a dictionary would be slower than a list?

Comment: @HFBrowning For instance, if the hash was slow to compute, had a lot of clashes, or if the collection was very small.

Comment: @DeepSpace, it's return `obj_to_save`. Sorry for ambiguity, I edited my question to be more precisely.

Comment: The `hash(self.p1)` should fail with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. (Ignoring the issue of whether a dictionary whose keys map to themselves is even useful.)

Comment: @martineau list is p2, this design working well, I'm not asking about it. I'm asking is there better way to do the same thing. If dictionary is list of (hash_of_item: item) pairs, this way allow to access item instance from list without looking all object. Right?

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment, you're right about the list being `p2`. I guess what doesn't make sense is that if you can create the object you want to look for, why to you need to look it up if you already have it? Not needing to look it up would be faster than doing so.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for answer. I try to explain: I create new object only to get hash of it (for search), obj_1 and obj_2 are not same, but have same hash. obj_1 have list `p2` and I want to access it. My logic: I have a lot of objects, they're stored in dict, p1 is immutable, but p2 can changing. If I got new p1=5 how can I find object with such p1? I create new object (python get it hash) and use it to find original object and access p2.

Comment: Just create a dict from your id, which seems to be integers, to the objects you care about.

Comment: Monitor-1: OK, think I now understand what your goal is. An issue with only using the hash of the `p1` value as a dictionary key is that, unless they're unique, they can't be used to look up the associated "real" object since dictionaries only hold one value per key. You could make each value a `list` to hold more than one object, but you're still going to need some way to determine which one of them is the one you want. If they are unique, then do as @juanpa.arrivillaga advises.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you mean use `p1` as id? No, it was simplified example, actually  it has more different 'primary' keys and I thought `hash` function good way to create such uniq 'id' for each object.

Comment: @martineau I'm not understand why I can't use p1 (or value of hash function of some objects attributes) as lookup value. One key - one value, ok. It's mean one p1 value - one associated object in dictionary? E.g. by `obj_1` have `p1=2`, in dictionary it's look like `d = {2: obj_1}`. If I want access obj_1 I just call `d[2]`. In my case I make something like `d[SomeHashableObject(2)]`

Comment: @Monitor-1 because **the hash value isn't what's used as the lookup in the dictionary**. The *hashable object is*. You could hack your way into the CPython internals, and try to do this. Or you could *just create the map you need directly*. Whatever your "primary keys" are, just use them as the object that will be the key directly. Having a dict that just maps the object to itself **makes no sense**

Comment: Monitor-1: If the `p1` values are unique, then they would be fine to use (directly) as the key for each value in the dictionary (whose associated value is the object having a `p1` attribute equal to that value). This means you don't need to define a custom `__hash__()` method—because you wouldn't be trying to use `SomeHashableObject` as dictionary keys. i.e. `obj_dict = {1: SomeHashableObject(1), 42: SomeHashableObject(42), etc. }`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga (and martineau) Ok, got yours point, thanks for your time. I thought something wrong here, but was not sure where exactly and why.